# Org Latex Preview: Generates SVG But Doesn't Display

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

I'm running Emacs v25.1 + Orgmode v9.0.9 on a Mac.

Based on [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151338/org-latex-preview-is-fuzzy-on-retina-displays), I changed my `org-latex-create-formula-image-program` to `dvisvgm` by adding the following to my `init.el`:

```
(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm)
```

I am trying to use `C-c C-x C-l` to preview some equations:
[image: latex equations to preview]

**Problem:** The images seem to be properly generated (they appear in the folder `ltximg`) ...
[image: svg properly generated]
but they are not displayed ...
[image: svg images not displayed]

**Question:** What is going on? Previewing the equations worked fine with `dvipng` (albeit at a lower resolution, that's why I'm trying to use `dvisvgm`), but with `dvisvgm` they are not being displayed and I don't get any errors. How can I fix it?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Generating seems to work. Are those Images valid svg images? Did you try to show an inline svg image in an org-mode file? Is this working? Do you have the program  `imagemagic` installed?

Comment: Generating image works, at least it generates svg files with the correct latex equations. The problem is that these images aren't displayed overlaying the equations. Following your suggestion, I tried showing an svg image using `C-c C-x C-v` and got `Invalid image type 'svg'`. Not sure about `imagemagic (k?)`, how can I check that?

Comment: Imagemagick :) It should be installed on your system via brew? I do not use a Mac, so I do not know. I see by comments, you found the other question about this topic. But did you also found this answer about installing SVG capable Emacs on Mac: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157144 ?

Comment: @jue Yes! Your comments led me to finding out that Emacs has to be compiled with `svg` support, as there is no other way to add svg support to it after compilation (don't know why, though). I first got my Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com, but I find out that a much much better Emacs is available from https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport. This other version is called Emacs Mac Port and it has svg support built-in, and many other "utilities" for Mac users. Thanks for helping!!! :D

Comment: you are welcome. You could write an answer and mark your question as answered, so the next Mac user can easily see your solution.

Comment: @jue done! thank you for helping! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why You Cannot Display SVG Images in Your Emacs**

In order to use `dvisvgm` properly, and have Emacs actually overlay the `svg` images, Emacs must be able to not only generate `svg` files, but also display them.

If you have a Latex package installed on your machine, like [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/), then you already have `dvisvgm` installed, and Emacs will be able to generate the `svg` images. The real problem lies in **displaying** the `svg` images in Emacs. To do so, the Emacs binary you are using must have been built with `svg` support.

If your Emacs has not been built with `svg` support, then it is not possible to add `svg` support by installing a package or modifying your `init.el` file (to the best of my knowledge). This is the case with the Emacs version from [emacsformacosx.com](https://emacsformacosx.com). This was the Emacs I was using, and it does not have `svg` support.

**Solution**

The easiest solution is to download another Emacs binary that has been compiled with `svg` support. I found another great Emacs binary for Mac users, that not only has `svg` support, but also extra utilities that can make use of a Mac's higher resolution displays. This binary can be found [on this github (Yamamoto's Emacs a.k.a. Emacs Mac Port)](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/releases).

If you download the most recent Emacs from the link above (at the time of writing it was Emacs 25.2 Mac 6.4), and add `(setq org-latex-create-formula-image-program 'dvisvgm)` to your `init.el`, then `C-c C-x C-l` will work, and the overlayed `svg` image will look great on your display:

[image: svg now works and equation looks great]

If you want to keep Emacs "lean", you can compile Emacs yourself, adding only support to `svg`.

Comment: Do you know if this situation has changed in the last years? Regarding sag support of https://emacsformacosx.com/.